# Destroying session

Tags: php

i want to destroy a session by clicking on a link. if i click on that link the session will be destroyed, otherwise not. I don't know the exact code for this, but i have tried with this one :

```
<?php
echo $sess_destory = "<a href='department.php'> Back </a>";

if($sess_destory)
{
session_destroy();  
}
?>
```

In this way, the session is simply destroying before the time i want. That's why the desired data cannot pass through the other page and showing the error below :

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id, semester, sem_id) VALUES ('','Second Year First Semester','2-1')' at line 1"

Comment: `echo $sess_destory = "<a href='department.php'> Back </a>";` hm... what do you want exactly?

Comment: destroy session after sql query!

Comment: i want to destroy session depending on a condition. but don't know the approproate way for it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a generic logout page..

```
<?
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location: index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I see a spelling mistake:

```
if($sess_destory) // should be destroy
{
session_destroy();  
}
```

But, the error you show has to do with an SQL statement

```
(id, semester, sem_id) VALUES ('','Second Year First Semester','2-1')
```

Don't know what it should be, but assuming ID is auto incremental, do it this way:

```
(semester, sem_id) VALUES ("Second Year First Semester","2-1")
```

Comment: when i remove the "session_destroy condition" then it runs perfectly with no error.